# Why does Mathf.Abs(MyClass v) call an implicit int conversion rather than an implicit float conversion in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, implicit-conversion

I'm using dynamic types and implicit conversions and am curious why the following code calls the implicit *int* conversion and not the implicit *float* conversion within my **TestClass**?

```
TestClass myVar = 1.6f;
var result = Mathf.Abs(myVar);
```

The value assigned from this code is essentially `Mathf.Abs(1)` rather than `Mathf.Abs(1.6f)`.

For reference, the following is my TestClass which is a contrived class for the purpose of this post.

```
class TestClass
{
    public dynamic variable;

    TestClass(dynamic v)
    {
        variable = v;
    }

    public static implicit operator float(TestClass v)
    {
        return (float)v.variable;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(TestClass v)
    {
        return (int)v.variable;
    }

    public static implicit operator TestClass(float v)
    {
        return new TestClass(v);
    }
}
```

*Ultimately I'm creating a class to mirror the functionality of another language which allows variables to be float, string or boolean (without specifically declaring the type) and casts appropriately at run-time depending on the operator or function to which they're being applied. The language in question is one designed to help children learn to code and handles any situation gracefully without crashing. This information isn't really required for the question but gives a general overview of the background.*

Comment: Because there are overloads for both `Mathf.Abs(int)` and `Mathf.Abs(float)` ... and your class provides both implicit conversions to `int` and `float` .. so the compiler chose (via whatever internal rules for preference) whatever he likes more ^^

Comment: @derHugo: No, not "internal rules for preference" - according to the rules of the C# specification. (I'm writing up an answer.)

Comment: @JonSkeet well that's what I mean of course but go ahead ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, we can reproduce this without needing Unity or dynamic typing. The following example prints 1, calling the `PrintValue(int)` overloads:

```cs
using System;

public class Wrapper
{
    private float value;

    public Wrapper(float value) => this.value = value;

    public static implicit operator float(Wrapper wrapper) =>
        wrapper.value;

    public static implicit operator int(Wrapper wrapper) =>
        (int) wrapper.value;
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(1.5f);
        PrintValue(wrapper);
    }

    static void PrintValue(float f) => Console.WriteLine(f);

    static void PrintValue(int i) => Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

The rules of overload resolution are described in the ECMA language specification [section 12.6.4](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/expressions.md#1264-overload-resolution). Both overloads of `PrintValue` are *applicable function members* because there's an implicit conversion from `Wrapper` to each of `float` and `int`.

In this case, `PrintValue(int)` ends up as the *better function member* because the conversion from `Wrapper` to `int` is a *better conversion from expression* than the conversion from `Wrapper` to `float` (12.6.4.4) because `int` is a better conversion target than `float` (12.6.4.6) because there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `float`, but there *isn't* an implicit conversion from `float` to `int`.

To put it another way: `int` is a sort of "more specific" parameter type than `float`, in the same way that `string` would be a "more specific" parameter than `object`. (Because of the implicit conversions available.)

Comment: I didn't doubt it could be reproduced with dynamic or Unity but the sample code was pretty lightweight as it was. That aside, thanks for the answer and the very useful links to ECMA specs. I'll simply add explicit casts when needed - I was just curious why this behaviour occurred and you've explained it very nicely.

Comment: @Rok: The sample code was small, but had unnecessary requirements - a lot of C# developers (myself included) don't have Unity, and I tend to simplify things as much as possible when reproducing problems. That definitely includes getting rid of `dynamic` as far a possible :)